# how to call a role id from a different platform stored in GitHub secrets to an AWS glue job code

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, github-actions, aws-glue

I have a few values stored in GitHub secrets that are called in the code of a glue job running in AWS. So, my workflow goes the following way GitHub -> AWS Glue -> S3 currently if I put the variables of the secrets in the code, the variables are not recognized. it gives the "undefined variable" error.
do the variables need to be stated in the ".YML" that runs the workflow?

The intent is to have something like this in my code (right now the values in Capital letters are explicit, which I'm trying to remove)

```
    # API info
    headers = {'role_id': ROLE_ID, 'Authorization': PLATFORM_TOKEN,
               'Content-Type': 'application/json'} 

    # consolidates the complete URL of the dataset
    full_url = [PROD_URL + ids for ids in datasets_ids]
```